# Embedded Jetty upload fails with Exception: Content-Type != multipart/form-data

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

Am new to Jetty and I want to use it to handle uploads. But I am getting an exception

```java
    //UploadHandler.java
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    public class UploadHandler extends AbstractHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
            String contentType=baseRequest.getContentType();
            Part infilepart=baseRequest.getPart("image");
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println("filename="+infilepart.getName()+" filesize="+infilepart.getSize()+" contentType="+contentType);
            baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        }
    }
```

Then the main file

```java
    //FileUploadExample.java
    import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;

    public class FileUploadExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            Server server=new Server(8080);
            ContextHandler ctxupload=new ContextHandler("/upload");
            ctxupload.setHandler(new UploadHandler());
            HandlerList handlerList=new HandlerList();
            handlerList.setHandlers(new Handler[]{ctxupload,new DefaultHandler()});
            server.setHandler(handlerList);
            server.start();
            server.join();
        }
    }
```

Then the Html form to test this app

```html
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image"/></br>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
```

But submitting causes an exception. How can I fix this?

```java
    HTTP ERROR 500

    Problem accessing /upload/. Reason:

        Server Error

    Caused by:

    javax.servlet.ServletException: Content-Type != multipart/form-data
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2332)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getPart(Request.java:2322)
        at UploadHandler.handle(UploadHandler.java:15)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

and even worse a breakpoint shows that it seems to be a "Get" request
[image]

This is the gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.4.19.v20190610'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Comment: So what does `String contentType=baseRequest.getContentType();` return in your handler when it's called?

Comment: The breakpoint is showing the `toString()` of the `baseRequest`, not the value of the `contentType` variable.

Comment: contentType is null

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt do you know of any working example of embedded jetty performing file upload? If yes link please

Comment: Example can be found at the embedded-jetty-cookbook - see: [MultipartMimeUploadExample.java](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/MultipartMimeUploadExample.java)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt You are awesome

Comment: Once you figure out your issue, please answer your own question here, let others know what you needed to do to fix it.